# Remove directory that is actually used by another process

Tags: linux, bash, debian, udev

I have udev rules that creates a directory for each usb-media that is plugged into my debian to automount usb-media. This directory where mount-points (the mount-directories) are created is passed through a rdp-connection with rdesktop. On our terminalserver there's a drive Z that shows all mount-points with content of usb-media.

When users remove usb-media, udev unmounts usb-media and tries to delete the directory that was used to mount usb-media. If the users hasn't closed explorer showing any subfolder of usb-media, the unmount-command succeeds but the rmdir-command fails because the ressource is "busy or used".

My question: how can I force to delete this mountpoint? (rmdir doesn't have force and rm -rf doesn't work)

*Edit*: I should add, that I can't use third-party software or additional packages because the linux-machine is a thin-client with very low disk-space.

Comment: This is not normally a problem. I'd look to Samba for the issue.

Comment: what should I exactly look at? I'm not a linux-professional, I just have a few basic skills...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder that I wasn't able to delete was a mount-point.
It wasn't unmounted as I pulled the usb-stick off of the thin-client because the server had the content of that stick shown in explorer. Using the -l switch for umount in the udev-rule helped to force umount when the stick was removed anyway. Deletion of that mount-point wasn't a problem anymore after unmounting the stick.